# Move pagecontrol dots to match current view location

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have 5 pages and I want to start on the 3rd page. I have added some code to skip to the 3rd page

```
CGRect frame = self.predictionsScroll.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * (pagesBefore);
frame.origin.y = 0;
[self.predictionsScroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

This works perfectly except the pageControl still shows that it is on the first page. If I drag the view a tiny bit it updates to where it is, but this should start on the middle dot. Here is my method for updating the pageControl page.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  if (scrollView == self.predictionsScroll) {
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.predictionsScroll.frame.size.width;
    float fractionalPage = self.predictionsScroll.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
    self.pagecontrol.currentPage=page;
  }
}
```

I have tried adding a manuel pagecontrol.currentPage = pagesBefore; But this does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure pagecontrol is not nil at the time you are performing the initial scrollview positioning?

Comment: well i added the code in 'pagecontrol.currentPage = pagesBefore;' when  I did the initial scroll positioning so it wont be null.